# Jmeter throws a Read Exception when sending message to server(middleware) through TCP sampler

Tags: tcp, jmeter, middleware

I'm using JMeter to load test middleware server using the TCP Sampler (TCPClientImpl class) for sending the following message:[message format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWwNP.png)
[Tcp Sampler setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vF1zo.png)

upon sending the request I am getting the 500 response code

**ERROR**

```
Response code:500
Response message:org.apache.jmeter.protocol.tcp.sampler.ReadException: Error reading from server, bytes read: 0
```

**LOGS**

```
2022-03-03 12:46:37,265 ERROR o.a.j.p.t.s.TCPSampler: 
org.apache.jmeter.protocol.tcp.sampler.ReadException: Error reading from server, bytes read: 0
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.tcp.sampler.TCPClientImpl.read(TCPClientImpl.java:122) ~[ApacheJMeter_tcp.jar:5.4.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.tcp.sampler.TCPSampler.sample(TCPSampler.java:398) [ApacheJMeter_tcp.jar:5.4.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:638) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:558) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:489) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:256) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.3]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) [?:?]
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedRead(NioSocketImpl.java:283) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.implRead(NioSocketImpl.java:309) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.read(NioSocketImpl.java:350) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl$1.read(NioSocketImpl.java:803) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.Socket$SocketInputStream.read(Socket.java:966) ~[?:?]
    at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:218) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.tcp.sampler.TCPClientImpl.read(TCPClientImpl.java:105) ~[ApacheJMeter_tcp.jar:5.4.3]
```

Comment: No it doesn't. It throws a read exception when ***reading.*** Look at the evidence you've provided. Your question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

It means that the sampler failed to receive the response within the bounds of the timeout you set to 2 seconds.

Try increasing the timeout in the TCP Sampler (or even better use [TCP Sampler Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#TCP_Sampler_Config), it acts like [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-its-so-important-use-jmeters-http-request-defaults) for the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers and the host, port, timeouts, etc. will be applied to all TCP Samplers you have)

If the error remains double check the network connectivity to the host/port combination where your TCP service lives using [telnet client](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/38433.windows-10-enabling-telnet-client.aspx) or equivalent software